# Localization - Getting page not found from CP when trying to edit new locale

Tags: localization, sections

I've set up a new locale fr_ca according to the localization guide. 
I've defined my site url's accordingly and set the files like so that english is on the top level and an fr_ca folder contains the index.php file.

I've set the craft folder accordingly, and defined CRAFT_LOCALE. 
I've also enabled the locale in all my sections.

Now when i access a singles entry, and I click Canadian French on the right to switch locales, I get a Page Not Found error, the requested URL was not found on this server.

I've also set my templates so that inside my templates folder, i have a folder fr_ca containing a new index.html file to be served. When I try to access the site from the front end, using www.example.com/fr_ca, I get an entry is not defined error (which makes sense).

Comment: the main concern is that the light to the right of the locale (Canadian French) is still white. What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 2):

When a new locale is added to an existing site, Craft re-saves the entries in the background. If you're unable to edit the entry in the new locale, it would indicate that the task has not completed. Check the craft_tasks table in your database to see if this is the case. [More info on stuck tasks here.](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/stuck-tasks)

Comment: i looked at the craft_tasks table and none of the rows have a status column that is still running. is there anyway I can fix my locales?

Comment: Are there any rows in the table at all? Are you seeing any errors in your logs?